# using startActivityForResult() and then finish()

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a view in my android app that needs to open another view

and also close\finish all the calling hierarchy that made it open.

How can i do this?

If i use this code, the finish() is never called no?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
setResult(RESULT_OK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: It will be called. So what you want to do is starting child activity and finishing parent activity?

Comment: do like this 
startActivity(new Intent(this, UI.class)
 .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

Comment: finish() will be of course executed

Comment: finish will be called normally as @Melquiades said. Your code will start a new activity and close the current activity

Comment: the `finish()` method is called in your case. If you want your activity to not get stored in the back stack , simply use `android:noHistory="true"` on the decalaration of your activity in the manifest

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with `startActivityForResult()` (which you have in the title of your question). I also don't understand how the "accepted answer" answers this question :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear whole stack using:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

this is a solution if you want to start new activity, and close all activities that were open before it.

Comment: Be aware that `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is only available from API level 11 (Android 3.0), so this won't work on devices running 1.x or 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

Google has an informative article on the Android back stack [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

In your code the `.finish()` is called and your calling activity should finish, but only that Activity and not others in the back stack. You can maintain some control of your back stack via Intent flags that are explained in the article, i.e.`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.

Another method is to use `startActivityForResult(...)` and close unwanted Activities in the `onActivityResult(..)` method in your `Activity` when it returns to the foreground..